# running mysql server and phpmyadmin in docker containers

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin

I spin up a docker container for `MySQL server`

```
docker run --detach --name=mysql_db_server --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password" mysql
```

Then I run another container for `phpmyadmin` that is linked to `MySQL server` as follows

```
docker run --name myadmin -d --link mysql_db_server:mysql -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

I am able to see `phpmyadmin` on `http://localhost:8080` but I am not able to log into it using either

`root`  --- `password` or 
`admin` --- `password`

[image: myphpadmin login]

`$docker ps -a`

output

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
85e68b8bab30        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/run.sh phpmyadmin"     3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   myadmin
b4d130cdb230        mysql                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          3306/tcp               mysql_db_server
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use myadmin  instead of mysql

```
docker run --name myadmin -d --link mysql_db_server:myadmin -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Docker Linking example https://gist.github.com/mtt2p/76b5488a07380b408ec568dc58027461

Comment: still no go. the docker ps -a seems correct to my eyes

Answer (score 0):

Log in to MySQL console with your user:

For that run the command -- **docker exec -it app_db_1 /bin/bash**

and now you can login to MYSQL console with your user:

**root@5f1d313df243:/# mysql -uroot -ppassword**
and change the Authentication Plugin with the password here:

mysql> ALTER USER root IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'PASS';

you will get output something like this  -- Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

exit

exit

Read more about the Preferred Authentication Plugin on the MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password

It will work perfectly with a docker as well as docker-compose:

now you can log in to phpMyAdmin on http://localhost:8080 with root & PASS.

(Don't use port 8080 because it might get a problem when your system already uses 8080 port other processes.)